# Unable to install anything on opensuse

Tags: opensuse

I am failing to install any software, I keep getting this error:

```
Retrieving repository 'openSUSE-Leap-42.3-Non-Oss' metadat[\]
Download (curl) error for 'http://download.opensuse.org/distribution/leap/42.3/repo/non-oss/repodata/repomd.xml':
Error code: Connection failed
Error message: Failed to connect to download.opensuse.org port 80: Connection refused
```

Comment: `netstat -pln | grep 80`  And also the download error is there, because the file does not exist.

Answer (score 1):

The problem seems to be your URL.

http://download.opensuse.org/distribution/leap/42.3/repo/non-oss/repodata/repomd.xml

Is getting a 404 (Not Found)

on the other hand, maybe you wanted to use this repo.

http://download.opensuse.org/distribution/leap/42.3/repo/non-oss/suse/repodata/repomd.xml

which is ok.

Try adding that repo to zypper

```
zypper addrepo <URI>
```

A more meaningful list of options could be found in [Suse Official Manual](https://www.suse.com/documentation/sles11/book_sle_admin/data/sec_zypper.html)